# ¿Como puede corregir el error: Error al intentar ejecutar el proyecto: Puntero no valido?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Hace poco tiempo instale Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 y para probar el IDE cree un proyecto nuevo en visual basic en windows form. No ingrese ningún código, ni agregue algún botón, `textbox`, `label` etc.. Solamente corrí con f5 el form que genera por defecto la aplicación y me genero un error que es el que esta reflejado como Titulo.

> Error al intentar ejecutar el proyecto: Puntero no valido

Soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación y desarrollo web, ademas de ser un nuevo usuario de esta fantastica plataforma.

Seria muy útil su ayuda y espero que me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Intenta ejecutar  Visual Studio como administrador y nos comentas si así funciona.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema y nose como corregirlo, alguien tiene alguna idea de como solucionarlo?